# Не сохраняется выбранная дата (air datepicker), как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Использую в работе air datepicker, в своем базисе этот плагин сохраняет выбранную дату и передает для отображения в браузере, записывает в value, то есть если пользователь захочет отредактировать дату в форме,то она будет ему доступна. 
Сделал фильтр выборки даты (что бы можно было выбрать дату идущую через 3 дня от текущей и все за ней последующие) но вот эта дата не отображается (не сохраняется) при редакции в браузере (обновлении страницы, редактировании формы), при этом ее значение в value есть.
Выходит что скрипт мешает выводу даты каким-то образом. 
В чем может быть проблема? и как это пофиксить?

```js
$('.datepicker-here').datepicker({

  onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
    if (cellType == 'day') {
      var today = new Date();
      today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      if (today && date <= +today + 86400000 * 3) {
        return {
          disabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  minDate: new Date(),

  position: "left bottom",

  language: {
    days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    daysShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    daysMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    today: 'Today',
    select: '',
    clear: 'clear',
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: '',
    firstDay: 1
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать это так:

```js
$(function() {
  var datepicker = $('.datepicker-here').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
      localStorage.setItem("datepickerDate", date);
    },
    onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
      if (cellType == 'day') {
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (today && date <= +today + 86400000 * 3) {
          return {
            disabled: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    minDate: new Date(),
    position: 'left bottom',
    language: {
        days: ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
        daysShort: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
        daysMin: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
        months: ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
        monthsShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
        today: 'Today',
        select: '',
        clear: 'clear',
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: '',
        firstDay: 1
    }
  }).data('datepicker');
  
  var selectedDate = localStorage.getItem("datepickerDate");
  if (selectedDate !== null && selectedDate !== '') datepicker.selectDate(new Date(selectedDate));
});
```